# How to define the lifetime for a struct holding on to a struct that uses lifetimes itself

Tags: rust

I try to load a dynamic library and use its functions. For that I rely on [`libloading`](https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/struct.Library.html).

I struggle with the lifetimes.

`libloading` provides a `Library` struct, that allows me to load the dynamic library (`Library::new`) and to get individual functions from it (`Library::get`).

```rust
pub unsafe fn get<'lib, T>(
    &'lib self,
    symbol: &[u8]
) -> Result<Symbol<'lib, T>, Error>
```

This defines a lifetime `'lib` referencing itself to make sure the library still exists when one calls its functions.

In my code I create struct `PlugPlug` that holds on the library and also its function (I don't want to call `Library::get` on every function call to avoid the overhead.). It exposes the library's function as a method (`my_function`).

As I need to define a lifetime for the `Symbol` holding the function from the lib, I've added `'dl` to my struct and also adjusted `load` to use this lifetime. This is probablby the wrong approach, as I now can't call `my_function` after `load` due to mutable/immutable borrow conflict (see `fn main()`below).

```rust
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};

pub struct PlugPlug<'dl> {
    dyn_module: Option<Library>,
    my_func: Option<Symbol<'dl, fn(&str) -> PlugPlugErrorCode>>,
}

impl<'dl> PlugPlug<'dl> {
    pub fn new() -> PlugPlug<'dl> {
        PlugPlug {
            dyn_module: None,
            my_func: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn load(&'dl mut self, path: &Path) -> Result<(), String> {
        // load dynamic library
        let lib = unsafe { Library::new(path) }.map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
        self.dyn_module = Some(lib);

        // load function from library
        unsafe {
            self.my_func = self
                .dyn_module
                .as_ref()
                .and_then(|lib| lib.get(b"THE_FUNCTION").ok());
        }
        if self.my_func.is_none()
        {
            return Err("Not all functions could be loaded".to_string());
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn my_function(&self, param: &str) -> Result<PlugPlugErrorCode, String> {
        match &self.my_func {
            Some(func) => {
                let result = unsafe { func(param) };
                Ok(result)
            }
            None => Err("Extension my_function not loaded".to_string()),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut plugplug = PlugPlug::new();
    plugplug.load(Path::new(&"libpath")); // <-- mutable borrow
    let ext = plugplug.my_function("THE_PARAMETER"); // <-- immutable borrow E0202
}
```

Even wrapping the mutable borrow into its own context doesn't help:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut plugplug;
    {
        plugplug = PlugPlug::new();
        plugplug.load(Path::new(&"libpath"));
    }
    let ext = plugplug.my_function("THE_PARAMETER"); // E0202
}
```

In the end, I'd want to use my struct's lifetime as the lifetime for the `Symbol` I retrieve via `get`, as my struct holds the library and when my struct goes away the library does, too.

How do I solve this? And why do I run into the lifetime problems with my approach?